How to prove that < implies <= for real numbers in Coq
Im trying to prove:
Local Open Scope ring_scope.
Local Open Scope ereal_scope.
Local Open Scope ldl_scope.
Context {R : realType}.

Lemma aku : forall x1 x2 : \bar R, (x1 < x2) -> (x1 <= x2).

But I don't have the first clue on how to start.

Please give us a minimal working example, in particular one where your Imports appear (currently, trying to run your example as is gives an error on line 1). Otherwise, we are lacking context to help you.
